# Make REST API calls with GoogleApiClient

Tags: android, rest, google-play-services, google-play-games, google-api-client

I have an Android app which uses Play Services' auth and Game APIs. Once I log the user in, I want to do a few actions. I found the appropriate action with their REST API, but have been unable to find a corresponding action in their Android library.

https://developers.google.com/games/services/web/api/leaderboards/list

I've been thinking of a few ways around this. Is there a way I can make a generic http request using the GoogleApiClient variable? Is there a way I can make a REST request using the oauth token I already have?

A web version of this app has already been developed, so I'm familiar with the REST API. I'm hoping I can port over to Android with minimal work.﻿

Comment: Were you able to find a generic way to handle REST google api calls once authenticated with GoogleApiClient ? I don't want to be bound by what already has autogenerated client code

Comment: No I never was able to handle REST calls in the Android app.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, there is a corresponding Android API (as there should be with all of the Games API calls (excepting the Game management APIs): [Leaderboards.loadLeaderboardMetadata()](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/leaderboard/Leaderboards.html#loadLeaderboardMetadata(com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient,%20boolean)) so you don't need to build any REST API calls.

Comment: Yes, there does seem to be Android-specific API for this case. As I continue to add functionality, I figure the codebase will continue to diversify.
If I wanted to build REST API calls, is there a good way of doing that?

Answer (score 0):

There already exists a Java REST api library.

I use it in a couple of apps that are compiled for Java/Desktop, Android, and iOS (via RoboVM).

https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/